# How to Insert an HTML file into a VUE component?

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to VueJS, so far everything is going well. But I have a few already made HTML templates that I want to insert into my components.

I've seen examples showing:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1gaa.png)

But that doesn't work (at least not for me).

Any ideas would help, thanks :)

Comment: Can you show an example what you want to achieve? You can use HTML inside `<template>`

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to import external html files into your vue templates.

The recommended way to author Vue component is using the [vue SFC format](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html#single-file-components) with a build tool like [Vite](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#project-scaffolding) or [Webpack](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#project-scaffolding). If you have a lot of static templates that you want to migrate to Vue SFCs you should probably copy/paste them into the `<template>` tags of your components manually.

You can also use Vue in a [standalone format](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/ways-of-using-vue.html#standalone-script) requiring no build tools but this won't allow you to import html files in your component's template either.